# How does the Galois group act on morphisms of varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let's say that I have two algebraic varieties $X$ and $Y$, both defined over a field $k$. Let $K/k$ be a Galois extension. How does the $\text{Gal}(K/k)$ act on morphisms $f:X_K \rightarrow Y_K$? It seems that if I have a morphism, I can look at the stabilizer of $f$ in $\text{Gal}(K/k)$ and then take the fixed field of that subgroup. If I call that fixed field $k'$, then is the morphism $f$ defined over $k'$?

When you are talking about morphisms defined over a smaller field, is it always with respect to the Galois action above? For example, if the Galois group acts differently on a morphism, and I do the same procedure with looking at the fixed field of the stabilizer, does that morphism descend?

Comment: It's helpful to do the example where $X$ and $Y$ are Zariski-closed in affine space, and the Galois action is just pointwise on coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be scheme over a field $k$ and let $K$ be a Galois extension of $k$. One then can define a morphism for each $\sigma$ in $\mathrm{Gal}(K/k)$

$$\sigma_{X,K}:X_K\to X_K$$

as $\sigma_{X,K}:=\mathrm{id}_X\times \mathrm{Spec}(\sigma^{-1})$ acting on $X_K=X\times_{\mathrm{Spec}(k)}\mathrm{Spec}(K)$. One can then check that

$$\sigma\mapsto \sigma_{X,K}$$

defines a homomorphism $\mathrm{Gal}(K/k)\to \mathrm{Aut}(X_K)$ where $\mathrm{Aut}(X_K)$ is the group of automorphisms of $X_K$ as an abstract scheme.

Suppose now that $Y$ is another $k$-scheme. The action of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/k)$ on $\mathrm{Hom}_K(X_K,Y_K)$ is given by

$$\sigma f:=\sigma_{Y,K}\circ f\circ \sigma_{X,K}^{-1}$$

It is then true that, with some minor hypotheses perhaps, that the map

$$\mathrm{Hom}_k(X,Y)\to \mathrm{Hom}_K(X_K,Y_K)$$

is injective with image precisely $\mathrm{Hom}_K(X_K,Y_K)^{\mathrm{Gal}(K/k)}$. Most of this can be deduced from [1, §4.4].

This should be sufficient to answer the rest of your questions, I believe.

[1] Poonen, B., 2017. *Rational points on varieties* (Vol. 186). American Mathematical Soc..

Comment: I should get that book.

Comment: @Notagradstudent It may be worth pointing out that a version of that text is [available on the author's website](https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf) for "incidental online use".